# Spring Controller with two methods differentiated by argument

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to write a REST interface to manage one of the resources in my application. Following best practice only I want to only use nouns as resource names.

I need the ability update the resource (a PUT operation) in one of several different ways. I imagine my user would call something like:

- /resource/{name}?Operation=DO&time=1&Unit=HOUR
- /resource/{name}?Operation=REDO&time=1&Unit=HOUR
- /resource/{name}?Operation=UNDO

(I'll probably have more then 3 operations, but this is enough to show what's going on). One of the important things that the operations have different arguments. Logically `time` and `Unit` do not make sense to the `UNDO` operation.

In my Java back end I'd like to implement this with two different methods each of which will have it's own `@RequestMapping` annotation. The differentiator will be the value of the `Operation` parameter.  I can't find any documentation that tells me how to do this

The alternative is to have a single method at the backend, but this is really ugly as I'll have to work out what combination of parameters is valid and throw my own 404 errors if they don't match!

Comment: If you need two different methods in controller, you need to move from query param to path param for the attributes. /resource/{name}/{time}/{unit}?operation=DO and /resource/{name}?Operation=UNDO

Comment: In "real" REST API there are no methods just resources https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer if you are planning to do something like RPC then SOAP web services are probably the better way.

Comment: @simas_ch. Thank you for your input. I am aware that REST operates with resources (hence the reason I said that I only wanted to use nouns in the resource name). REST does support  'operations such as GET or DELETE' (quote from wikipedia). The API is implemented in Java by annotating a method with `@RequestMapping`. I understand that REST its self does not have a concept of a 'method'. From the external view this is just an implementation detail

Comment: If you want to stay with the query params then you the only possibility is to proces the operation parameter in the method code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need 2 controllers then do something like

```
/resource/do/{name}/{time}/{unit}

/resource/undo/{name}
```

Comment: I was worried that might be the answer - It does mean that I've got to put a verb (do/undo) into the URL which feels un-rest like.

Comment: It shouldn't feel weird since it's two completely different things